# How to use calculateX method of AWSCognitoIdentityProviderSrpHelper in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I want to use AWSCognitoIdentityProviderSrpHelper methods in my ios Swift project for calculateX, calculateXHash and I also need to use AWSJKBigInteger.

I have installed the AWSMobileClient pod and inside the pods folder AWSCognitoIdentityProviderSrpHelper file is available but I cannot access it.

Here is the Github link: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/main/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider/Internal/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderSrpHelper.m#LL428C22-L428C32

If anyone has an idea please let me know.

Thanks!